# Why is this simple regression (keras) ANN is failing so bad?

Tags: r, optimization, keras, regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to do a non-linear regression on a very simple data. When running the following code i got really bad results. Almost every time the result is a simple linear regression. When i check the weights of my model most (if not all) neurons are 'dead'. They all have negative weights with negative biases making the ReLu function to return 0 for all inputs (since all inputs are in the range [0,1]).

As far as i can tell this is a problem with the optimizer. I also tried using a very low and a very high learning rate, no luck. The optimizer seems to be getting stuck in a 'very' sub optimal local minima.

I also tried to set the initial weights to be all positive [0,0.1], the optimizer 'cheats' its way into a linear regression by setting all biases roughly at the same value.

Any can help me? what i am doing wrong? Is this really the best a state of the art ANN can achieve on a simple regression problem?

```
library(keras)
fun <- function(x) 0.2+0.4*x^2+0.3*x*sin(15*x)+0.05*cos(50*x).

x_test <- seq(0,1,0.01)
y_test <- fun(x_test)
plot(x_test, y_test, type = 'l')

x_train <- runif(50)
y_train <- fun(x_train)
points(x_train, y_train)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(10, 'relu', input_shape = 1) %>%
  layer_dense(1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'sgd',
  loss = "mse"
)

history <- model %>% 
  fit(x = x_train, y = y_train,
      epochs = 100,
      batch_size = 10,
      validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
  )

y_pred <- model %>% predict(x_test)

plot(x_test, y_test, type = 'l')
points(x_train, y_train)
lines(x_test, y_pred, col = 'red')
```

[predicted outputs versus actual ones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRaW6.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you are using sigmoid function in hidden layer. Firstly regression shouldn't have sigmoid function,secondly sigmoid is mostly  used in last layer for classification purpose. Removing it and using relu should help.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, i fixed the code now. I tried all activation functions, but no luck.

Comment: learning rate can be a problem. I suppose high learning rate is causing your weights to shift too much and once they get negative, relu just clips the activations. This process might be repeating.

Comment: Changing the learning rate to 0.0001 and the epochs to 10000 didnt help at all

Comment: I tried this myself. Use the following config dense(24)->relu ->dense(32)-> relu with Adam optimiser and 0.001 lr. This easily overfits in 50 epoches.. don't do thousands. And use batch size of 5-10

Answer (score 0):

Change sigmoid with relu activation and fix your ) type error in the end of sgd.

EDIT

Also add a second dense layer  and train for much more epochs, like this:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(10, 'relu', input_shape = 1) %>%
  layer_dense(10, 'relu') %>%
  layer_dense(1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'sgd',
loss = "mse"
)

history <- model %>% 
  fit(x = x_train, y = y_train,
      epochs = 2000,
      batch_size = 10,
      validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
  )
```

Comment: Fixed both typos, i tried all activation functions on the hidden layer but no luck

Comment: add more neurons

Comment: Adding more neuros is definitely not the case, a well trained 10 neurons should be able to fit the model much better than this. The problem is not with model capacity, is definitely optimization problem.

Comment: You are right, I just edited my answer, this should work.